# How to use git svn to clone only some modules

Tags: git, svn

We run a company wide SVN and the software and projects there are separate modules, each with their own tags and branches, i.e. like this:

```
svn ls http://svn-emea.company.org/svn | more
module-1/
module-2/
...
svn ls http://svn-emea.company.org/svn/module-1/ | more
branches/
tags/
trunk/
```

We only want to move some of these modules to git and gitlab.com, but when I now say:

```
git svn clone http://svn-emea.company.org/svn/module-1/ \
      --authors-file=../users.txt --no-metadata --prefix "" -s module-1
```

`git svn clone` says it has to clone everything below /svn/ . The messages are:

```
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint:
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint:
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint:
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /data/devhome/git/module-1/.git/
Using higher level of URL: http://svn-emea.company.org/svn/module-1 => http://svn-emea.company.org/svn
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 100, path '/module-1'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Cecked through r89600
^C
(I hit Ctrl-C)
```

Why is this and how could we clone certain modules only, but in every case with tag, branches and trunk?

The history of the modules have been based on CVS checkoputs and svn import of the trees many years ago, in 2008 IIRC.

Comment: I think what you are doing is correct... seeing the output of the command in the question (_as text_, please) would be awesome. Is history of the module started by copying from somwhere else? Because `git-svn` likes to track down stuff like that, in my experience.

Comment: I added the messages to my original post.

Comment: Looks like standard output from `git-svn` when cloning. What makes you think that it will do stuff from the root of the repo?

Comment: The line: Using higher level of URL: http://svn-emea.company.org/svn/module-1 => http://svn-emea.company.org/svn , but maybe I interpret it bad; and I have an additional problem: it says at different files in different attempts of the same cloning:         A       sisms/util/imakeall
        A       sisms/util/makeall
fatal: name consists only of disallowed characters:
32768 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 476. And I do not get what is causing this problem; maybe I should file another separate question for this

Comment: I would not mind about it (the warning, I mean). When it starts creating commits, check one of them and see what it contains.

Comment: The error msg "32768 at  ..." was caused by me and took me two days to nail it down. In the author mapping file I've had the lines simple without the fullname like "apitzm = <apitzm@company.org>" while they should read  "apitzm = Matthias Apitz <apitzm@company.org>". If the error msg would have said "fullname" and not only "name consists only of disallowed chars" I would have understood it in two minutes... Thread closed.